# Как у jquery узнать какой код повесили на событие, при инспекции элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, события

На странице есть модальное окно, нажимаю на "крестик", окно закрывается. Мне нужно узнать где тот самый код который исполняется после нажатия на "крестик".

Как я делаю:

1. Открываю `Developer Tools`.
2. Во вкладке "элементы" выделяю нужный "крестик".
3. В `Event Listeners` фильтрую по выбранному элементу, и вижу событие `click`.

Это событие ссылается на **jQuery.event.add**.
И все бы хорошо, но на этом я не знаю что дальше делать, в объекте `jQuery` не нахожу где же тот калбэк который повесили на это событие с помощью `jQuery`.

P. S. Грепать я могу и, наверное, пока получу тут ответ, я уже найду нужный мне калбэк, но в целях образования хочу узнать.
P. P. S. Увидел что такой вопрос уже задавали и ответа не дали, только попросили поставить брейкпоинт в никуда :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть плагин для Chrome называется jQuery Audit.
Думаю, что должен помочь.

Comment: а если используеться jquery proxyHandler? тоесть jQuery Audit показывает на jquery функцию, и ничего об ориганиле